# How to query a transaction via the rpc interface

Tags: transactions

How to find a transaction by operation hash

Comment: Disagree with @Ezy, this is not a duplicate. The mentioned question concerns building an indexer, but this question concerns querying data from rpc. Yes, one can find answer to this question in the introducion to the mentioned question. But the questions actually aren't the same.

Comment: The strict answer to the question is « not it is not possible ». While correct it would a waste not to provide the better context which is offered by the other question. Just trying to be pragmatic here and add value to the reader who would end up here.

Comment: @Ezy Sometimes getting a short answer to a short question is much more preferable and saves a lot of time. Your question is quite abstract and aimed to discussing the problem, while this question is concrete and allows to quickly obtain the necessary information, especially via search engines. If you think you have a better context, just post the answer reffered to that context. This is how stack exchange works, I think =)

Comment: @Groxan well your answer is here isn’t it ? I just closed the question. Did not delete ur answer

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get an operation by hash via rpc api. Use block explorers instead.